# Getting Expected Log Out Time based on Log In Time

Tags: javascript, html

We are using a third party web app that only shows the number of minutes early (with respect to End of Grace Period), not your log in time. I am working on a code that shows your log in time based on the number of minutes early while we are working out the proposed changes to the vendor of the third party web app.

I was able to get the log in time but I could not get the expected log out time, which is after 9 hours (ideally!).

For example, if I am expected to be logged in before 9:00AM and I am 30 minutes early, then my log in time is 8:30 AM and my expected log out time is at 5:30 PM. The page is showing the same output for login and logout times. There must be an issue with adding minutes to the date.

```js
function getLoginTime(endofGP, minutes) {
  var d = new Date();
  const msperminute = 60000;
  minutes = document.getElementById("minutesearly").value;
  var endOption = document.getElementById("end").value;
  if (endOption == "1") {
    endofGP = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), 8, 0, 0, 0);
  } else if (endOption == "2") {
    endofGP = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), 8, 30, 0, 0);
  } else if (endOption == "3") {
    endofGP = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), 9, 0, 0, 0);
  } else if (endOption == "4") {
    endofGP = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), 9, 30, 0, 0);
  } else if (endOption == "5") {
    endofGP = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), 10, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  var login = new Date(endofGP - (minutes * msperminute)); //Get log in time
  var logout = new Date(login + (540 * msperminute)); //Get expected log out time
  document.getElementById("logintime").innerHTML = login;
  document.getElementById("logouttime").innerHTML = logout;
}

function clearMinutes() {
  document.getElementById("minutesearly").value = "";
}
```

```html
<h2>GET LOG IN TIME</h2>

<form autocomplete="off">
  <label for="end">Select End of Grace Period</label><br>
  <select id="end" name="end" onchange = "clearMinutes()">
    <option value="">Please select</option>    
    <option value="1">8:00 AM</option>
    <option value="2">8:30 AM</option>
    <option value="3">9:00 AM</option>
    <option value="4">9:30 AM</option>
    <option value="5">10:00 AM</option>
  </select><br>
  <label for="minutesearly">Minutes Early</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="minutesearly" oninput = "getLoginTime()"><br>
</form>

<p id="logintime">LOG IN TIME</p>
<p id="logouttime">LOG OUT TIME</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the function a little to avoid all of the if statements since we only really need to grab the options text to get the different components needed to generate the date object.

Then we use `setMinutes` to add the 9 hours onto the login time

```js
function loginTime(){
  let d = new Date();
  let minutes = document.getElementById('minutesearly').value || 0;
  const msperminute = 60000;
  let end = document.getElementById('end');
  let endValue = end.options[end.selectedIndex].text
  let hour = endValue.split(':')[0];
  let minute = endValue.split(':')[1].replace(/AM\b/g,'').trim() || 0;
  let endGP = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), hour, minute, 0, 0);
 
  let login = new Date(endGP - (minutes * msperminute)); //Get log in time
  let logout = new Date ( login );
  logout.setMinutes(logout.getMinutes() + 540 );

  document.getElementById("logintime").innerHTML = login;
  document.getElementById("logouttime").innerHTML = logout;
  
}
```

```html
<h2>GET LOG IN TIME</h2>

<form autocomplete="off">
  <label for="end">Select End of Grace Period</label><br>
  <select id="end" name="end" onchange = "loginTime()">
    <option value="">Please select</option>    
    <option value="1">8:00 AM</option>
    <option value="2">8:30 AM</option>
    <option value="3">9:00 AM</option>
    <option value="4">9:30 AM</option>
    <option value="5">10:00 AM</option>
  </select><br>
  <label for="minutesearly">Minutes Early</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="minutesearly" oninput = "loginTime()"><br>
</form>

<p id="logintime">LOG IN TIME</p>
<p id="logouttime">LOG OUT TIME</p>
```